# I'm using "protected" instead of "private", because someday I could need to extend my classes, is that bad?

Tags: private, extensibility, protected

I have noticed a pattern in my code. I usually choose `protected`, rather than `private`, as default access label for "hidden" methods and fields in my classes. I mainly do this because it hides the details about the class functioning for users of the class, while still leaving space for extension in the future. Is there any drawback in this coding "policy"?

Thank you
Tunnuz

Comment: The point is that you should have a *reason* for making either choice. Not sure how I can make that long enough to constitute an answer. If a future subclass might need to override a particular method, make it `protected`. If there's no way that it would need to be overridden (i.e., it's some integral functionality that makes this class what it is, and overriding it would break the class altogether), make it private. I don't understand this drive to find a "one-size-fits-all" rule I see so often on here.

Comment: Ok, of course you have to reason when you code. However there are situations (in which I'm finding myself quite often these days) where I don't know if a class could be extended someday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking never make something because some day you might be having to implement or do yadayada (it just makes life complicated and miserable Imho..). If you have a method that should only be used within its class, then make it private. If you ever have to extend it by inheritance than reconsider which functions might have to accessed from bellow. Usually I anyway abstract methods to my superclass so then I anyway have to do the thinking of what will be needed when and where..

A good reason why to ignore what I said about private methods, is if you want to test your internal functions i.e. in a unit test. In C# you can allow another project to see your protected methods from externally so you can write tests against them.

Comment: The only time `private` is really advantageous over `protected` is if future versions of the base class might benefit from changing the behavior of the member in question.  Otherwise, I would suggest that if one can't articulate a reason why future versions of the base might want to change the behavior, it's probably more likely that future derived classes might benefit from being able to access the member in question.

Answer (score 2):

You should choose private , because of encapsulation. I do prefer conservative approach on this subject, I prefer private access modifier, if I do expect some extension  then I choose protected access modifier. It is not good practice to choose protected modifier instead of private.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a drawback.

- Private variables, are variables that are visible only to the class to which they belong.
- Protected variables, are variables that are visible only to the class to which they belong, and any subclasses.

So everything should be ok with your code. There's nothing "bad" about that. If you probably extend your class, the protected property will be definately right.